# Google Analytics - View doesn't report correct data when filtered with a Custom Dimension

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I've set up a Custom Dimension at the website and the data is being registered correctly, as I am able to segment standard reports with a secondary dimension (using this Custom Dimension) and also to use this Custom Dimension as a segment.

However, when I set up a new View in GA filtering by this Custom Dimension, I see less than 20% of the data (sessions, pageviews, transactions, etc.) compared to what I see in a view without filters, but segmenting with the same Custom Dimension.

Has anybody had this kind of problem?

Comment: One type of solution is to make sure the dimensions are always loading. In my case I had to customize the Analytics integration for Google AMP and Facebook Instant Articles to also insert the dimensions there. I assume you already did this, but it's something that can help.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem where some traffic is just missing the dimension data, even though the hits are registered in Analytics, so the hits show when I search for the relevant URLs in the main reports, but the post IDs i set through dimensions don't pick up the traffic. It's spooky and super hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue of the scope. For example, include view filter requires that filtered dimension be present in every hit. So if you're using session level custom dimension and only send it once per session then only 1 pageview will be there in filtered view. Contrary, Session segment requires that the filtered dimension appear at least once in the session and include all of the particular session hits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But I tried that one and it didn't help. The problem is that there is a huge difference on all levels: users, sessions, pageviews, etc. Initially I had the scope set to session level. Then I changed it to hit level, but it didn't change much...